# pattern matching on String in Rust Language

Tags: string, rust

Is possible to parse the `<path>` part from `GET /<path> HTTP/1.1` using pattern matching, or anything gracefully rather than direct string manipulation such as `split` or `slice`

Answer (score 3):

No. Pattern matching does not do partial string matching. Splitting and slicing and iterating are the only ways you can get the contents of it.